# Zip code query for website

Tags: mysql, zipcode

The front page of my business' website is HTML (built in iWeb).  This front page links to several stores that serve separate geographic regions.  My business is undergoing a major expansion, so rather than providing links to each substore, I would like to allow customers to simply enter their zip code to link to the appropriate sub store serving their geographic area.  Can anyone offer a code snippet that would allow me to do this?  I can set up a MySQL database on my server that associates each zip code with the appropriate link to that geographic area's substore. How would I configure this snippet to pull information from the MySQL database?

Comment: Something like this? http://www.bjornblog.com/web/jquery-store-locator-plugin

Answer (score 0):

How many stores are we talking about?  10?  100?  10,000?

Also how close are the stores?  If you think of the an area like territories, you can relate the store to the first three of the zip to get a much shorter list of searchable store->Zip codes.

for example, 17401 search would go look for an entry in the store to zip code database by looking for 174.  That way no matter what the ending two characters of the zip were, you could always find the correct store without having to have each zip (there are 44K US codes) in your tables.

Hope this helps.